# Fixing an image to 3 coordinates in Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, figure

I have a Matlab code which creates a plot as shown below and overwrites the plot 500 times. Those 500 plots are considered as 500 frames and it creates a movie of these 500 frames later.

[image]

In each frame the locations of `D`, `H`, `B1`, `B2` and `B3` change. I want to fix the below image to the `B1`, `B2`, `B3` coordinates of the plot. So that if `B1`, `B2`, `B3` move the figure also moves with it.

[image]

Is it possible? I have no idea how to do it. Help is much needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is doable. You need to transform your figure to the coordinates of `B1..3` for each frame.
To do so, you need to know the xy locations of `B1..3` of the figure (let's denote them as `movingB1..3`), then you need the xy location of `B1..3` of the plot (let's denote them as `fixedB1..3`).
Now, for each frame, use [`cp2tform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html) to find the [`'affine'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html#inputarg_transformtype) transformation that maps `movingB1..3` to `fixedB1..3`.
Once you have the transformation, use [`tformarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/tformarray.html) to transform the figure to the proper location in the plot, and then plot over if your graph.

I strongly advise not to use `imtransform` as it has non-trivial support in translation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need to scale down the image before transforming it?

Comment: @Darshan the affine transformation should take care of the scaling for you: it maps the 3 2D points in `movingB1..3` to the 3 2D points on your plot `fixedB1..3. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Ok I have made a matrix called BucketMap using cp2tform. Can you please help me with tformarray? For A I have put 'BucketOnly.jpg' and for T I put BucketMap. I am not sure what to put for R, TDIMS_A, TDIMS_B, TSIZE_B, TMAP_B and F.

Sorry I have never used tformarray.